# Legowelt whistle like lead

Tags: synthesizer

How is the following lead achieved and how might I recreate something like it in Logic Pro X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey so I recreated this with my prophet but sure you could get the same sound in another place:

heres the outcome:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7u6sri5SdsY0hvQXFFUThGTEk/view?usp=sharing

So I used two triangle waves, detuned slightly, one an octave higher than the other.  12db low pass filter that is at about 10percent which opens up with envelope filter to about 75-80%. Resonance at about 25-30% Sync the wave

Amp envelope
10% Attack on  Max sustain 35% release

Filter Envelope
15% attack Max Sustain  15% release

Reverb with maybe a second of a tail,  very slight predelay, 15 seconds.  A Plate or Hall reverb should be nice here.

Included is an image of the patch on the prophet for further detail.  Can play around with some high pass to cut out some lows.  Hope that helped.

[image]